# Confirming code for redirect main domain but not the sub-domain

Tags: 301-redirect

We first had (22 years ago) the domain silver-cross.com and a few years later acquired silvercross.com Currently, silver-cross.com and silvercross.com are both using the same index file & we would like to fix this. What concerns us is that if we do a 301 permanent redirect from silver-cross.com to silvercross.com this may affect the lead database which is on our sub-domain survey.silver-cross.com

Can anybody please confirm the following code for this issue?

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect anything except survey.silver-cross.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(survey)\.silver-cross.com$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.silver-cross\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.silvercross\.com" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What do you mean "this may affect the database"?  Have you tried implementing the redirect in a staging environment, to see if it does what you want and your database still works?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew. Currently we don't have staging site so that's why I need to confirm above code that is that correct way to implement it? Our lead database is on sub-domain of old site that we don't want to redirect it.